# unsortedtype overloaded assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm currently using my debugger to work out a program in which a word is checked in a dictionary full of words, and then states whether it is a word or not, and states the meaning. When using the debugger, I get the following errors...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. std::string::assign (this=0x7fffffffdfe0,
__str=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffe8>) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:249 249 _CharT* __tmp = __str._M_rep()->_M_grab(__a,
__str.get_allocator());

#0 std::string::assign (this=0x7fffffffdfe0,
__str=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffe8>) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:249
#1 0x0000000000401bdd in DictEntry::operator= (this=0x7fffffffdfe0) at DictEntry.h:7
#2 0x0000000000402b31 in main () at main.cpp:81
```

This leads me to believe that it has something to do with my assignment operator overload. Could anyone help me fix the issue? Thank you! Below is the assignment operator...

```
UnsortedType & UnsortedType::operator=(const UnsortedType & right) //assignment operator overload 
{
if (this != &right) // if this object isn't the same object as the right
        {
                if (info != NULL)//It's our responsibility to set info appropriately
                        delete [] info;

                this->length = right.length;
                size = right.length;


        for (int i = 0; i < right.length; i++)
        {
        info[i] = right.info[i];
        length = size;
                //copy data
        }
        return (*this);

        }
}
```

In case anyone would like to see the main, just to get an idea of how the program is supposed to work, this is how I wrote it. Thanks again!

```
bool InitDictFromFile (SortedType & dict, const char *fileName)
{
  ifstream inFile;              //declare a ifstream object

  // open the file
  inFile.open (fileName);       //connect the inFile with disk file 
  // given by path name fileName

  if (!inFile)                  //if something went wrong, e.g., file nonexist,...
    {
      cerr << "failed to open " << fileName << endl;
      return false;
    }

  // keep reading a string from the file, put it into the dict
  while (!inFile.eof ())        //while we haven't reached end of file yet
    {
      string word;
      inFile >> word;

        if (inFile.eof()){
                break;
        }

        string meaning;
        getline (inFile, meaning);

        cout <<"Read word" << word << endl;
        cout <<"Read meaning" << meaning << endl;

        dict.PutItem (DictEntry (word, meaning));
 }

  inFile.close();
  dict.Print();
  return true;
}

int main ()
{
SortedType dict1, dict2;
  char cont;
  string word;
  DictEntry result;
  bool found;

  InitDictFromFile (dict1, "words.txt");
  InitDictFromFile (dict2, "cswords.txt");

 //create a dictionary that includes words from both 
 SortedType dict = dict1 + dict2;


  do {

        cout <<"Enter a word to check spell:";
        cin >> word;


        //Call the GetItem that SortedType class inherits from UnsortedType (which implements
        //"linear search") 
        result = dict.GetItem (DictEntry (word),found);
        if (!found)
                cout <<"Not a word\n";
        else
        {
                cout <<"Found the word\n";
                cout <<"Meaning " << result.GetMeaning() <<endl;
        }

        result = dict.UnsortedType::GetItem (DictEntry (word),found);
        if (!found)
                cout <<"Not a word\n";
        else
        {
                cout <<"Found the word\n";
                cout <<"Meaning " << result.GetMeaning() <<endl;
        }

        cout <<"Continue?";
        cin >> cont;

  } while (cont=='Y' || cont=='y');

}
```

Comment: You should be gettin compiler warning from the assignment operator function, not all paths return something.

Comment: You have the debugger going, and that's the right place to start. What happens when you step through the function? You might see that you `delete`d something and never allocated a `new` one before assigning to it.

Comment: I also recommend you read ["Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) (though you sidestep the issue by having another (unnecessary) check.

Comment: hi, I'm actually not getting any compiler warnings at all, when I compile all of my program, and I try to input a word, I get a segmentation fault (core dump)

Comment: furthermore, I'm pretty new to using gdb so it's a little tough to work with for me. So far that's how I was able to identify the problem.

Comment: No worries. While you should be getting the warnings @JoachimPileborg pointed out, and they will bite you later if you don't resolve them, your segfault is not syntactic. It's purely logical. The compiler won't catch it for you, but stepping through the assignment operator a few times should. I don't want to point you right at it because all the information is there. Crash point is `std::string::assign`. Where in `operator=` do you assign a `std::string`? Find that and look up a few lines and you should see the mistake.